# Django context processor : views does not reload

Tags: django, django-views

I built an application with Django that contains a certain number of views. I have to switch from one project to another which use the same views.

For this I used a context processor that returns the variables that change in a dictionnary. Then in all my views I return a `context_instance=RequestContext(request)`

My problem is that my views do not reload until I click a second time on the button "Change the project".

I don't know if I'm clear enough, but if someone could give me a hint on what is wrong here it would be great.
I don't even know what piece of code would help understand the issue, so if you think you can help please ask !

**EDIT**

A sample of my context_processor

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.template import RequestContext

def display_select_proj(request):
if request.method == "POST" and (request.POST.get("action", "") == "OK"):
     form = SelectForm(request.POST, proj_id=request.session['proj'])
     if form.is_valid():
         p = form.save()
         request.session['proj'] = proj

         return {'my_variables': my_variables}
```

Comment: please post sample codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context processor is not a proper place for such kind of logic, especially session modification. You should move it to [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) or view function.

Why your approach doesn't work: context processors just modify the context of template being rendered and are applied after your view function. [See "When context processors are applied"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/).

Comment: Oh, right ! Now it makes a lot of sense ! I never actually realised that..
Do you have examples of middleware use, I don't yet understand how this can work.

Comment: You can make [process-request middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-request) which will modify session as you need (and dont forget to include your custom middleware after `SessionMiddleware`. But I think a proper place for this logic is a view function, because you deal with form.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. The reason I used a context processor is because I need the form available in all pages. Can it still work with a middleware or a view ?

Comment: If you need a form to be on every page - use context processor. But handle form (save, check validation) should a view, I think.